# UIPanGestureRecognizer immediate feedback

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So this code is moving my blocks (UIImages) around fine, however, when I move a certain colored block (we'll say a bright green block) overtop the matching bright green circle, nothing happens until I start to move another block, then it finally recognizes the previous move was a match. Do I have my match detection (which is the following) in the wrong spot of the function?

```
if (100 / 2 > sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y))) && 
    myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor == myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor
```

..

```
@IBAction func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    let objectDragging = recognizer.view?.tag
    let pos1 = myBlocks[objectDragging!].center
    let pos2 = myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].center

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed) && ((100 / 2 > sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y))) && myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor == myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor) {

        print("match")
        myBlocks[objectDragging!].isHidden = true
        myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        print(objectDragging ?? 20)
        //print(myBlocks[objectDragging!])

        print("the tag of the object your touching is \(myBlocks[objectDragging!])")
    }


    else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

        if (100 / 2 > sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y))) && myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor == myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor {
            print("match")
            myBlocks[objectDragging!].isHidden = true
            myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }


    }
    else {

        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        //if object matches object in recognizer
    }
}
```

Edit & [GIF 1](https://i.imgur.com/ldWY5aF.gifv) of behavior and [GIF 2](https://i.imgur.com/cu1GL26.gifv):
Notice in the first how I make a match and as soon as I move the next block, it registers that match. However, in the 2nd gif you'll notice it only seems to register the match if the block you move after a match has it's circle revealed. By that I mean I made the match, then moved a few blocks, which did nothing, until I moved that dark red one (who's circle was revealed by moving the green block). So it seems to only match after a match is made, and another block of which has it's corresponding circle revealed is moved. Very strange.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    let objectDragging = recognizer.view?.tag

    let pos1 = myBlocks[objectDragging!].center
    let pos2 = myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].center


    switch(recognizer.state) {
    case .began:
        if ((100 / 2 > sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y))) && myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor == myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor) {

            myBlocks[objectDragging!].isHidden = true
            myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            print(".began")

        }
    case .changed:

        if ((100 / 2 > sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y))) && myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor == myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor) {

            myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
            myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            print(".changed")

        }

    case .ended:

        if ((100 / 2 > sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y))) && myBlocks[objectDragging!].tintColor == myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor) {

            myBlocks[objectDragging!].isHidden = true
            myCircles[myBlocks[objectDragging!].tag].tintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            print(".ended")

        }

    default:
        break
    }

    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: I *think* your code looks good. You seem to be saying the pan gesture itself works and that the if statement on state.ended does what it should (hides a block and changes a tintColor on another, correct?) but it's happening later than expected. Maybe you need a `setNeedsDisplay` inside that if?

Comment: Is that a sort of _refresh_ for the view? If that's the case I think that could help. Do I declare a setNeedsDisplay function and then just call it in the if? And you're exactly right with the thought that it is indeed hiding the block, and changing the tintColor of the corresponding matching colored circle.

Comment: view.setNeedsDisplay() — that didn't seem to do it, though after reading about it I thought that would have worked. I must have overlooked something in my code.

Comment: Nothing else jumps out at me, provided I' understanding what you expect: (1) User pans a colored square over the same colored circle, then (2) when user is finished panning the square is hidden and the circle changes color. And what is happening is #1 but while #2 happens, it's *only* when a new pan gesture begins. Wait! Your if... part one is .began *and* .changed, part two is .ended, and... an else? I might have thought that else should be the .changed. Maybe recode something there. (That's such a monster equation too... maybe change the **if** to a **switch** and default to a break?)

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. Very frustrating. Maybe I'll try a switch. Thank you

Comment: At the very least, it's something we can work with - the code is more easy to debug. Break it down into various components (I mean, break up the .begin, .change, *and* the monster calc into separate components. Post that code if nothing jumps out at you. (I'm not sure, maybe make it an edit to this OP?) I'll see if anything jumps out at me.

Comment: I changed into a switch, which looks a little more neat. However, I added the if statement to each to start off, hoping it would register for one of them. It's functioning the same pretty much. I added two little GIFs as well to my edit up there (sorry, the one slowed down a bit) but it shows the weird behavior. Is it something outside of my movement maybe? The logic seems to be working though.. confusing.